# Day of the Week, Month, Year, Week of the Year in R

Tags: r

Are there any built on functions that can be used on a data frame object to generate variables on a class `Date` time series to create day of the Week, Month, Year, Week of the Year, etc in R?

The `weekdays`, `months`, `quarters`, functions in the base package generate text output, looking for numerical output to denote that 3/5/2012, for example, is a Friday, 3rd day of the month, 1 week of the month, and the 63 day of the year, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a few of those just from `POSIXlt`, with its weird convention. Year needs to 1900,
month is on the 0 to 11 range -- but you do get weekday and day-of-the-year.

```
R> dd <- as.Date("2012-05-03")
R> as.POSIXlt(dd)
[1] "2012-05-03 UTC"
```

Then

```
R> unclass(as.POSIXlt(dd))
$sec
[1] 0

$min
[1] 0

$hour
[1] 0

$mday
[1] 3

$mon
[1] 4

$year
[1] 112

$wday
[1] 4

$yday
[1] 123

$isdst
[1] 0

attr(,"tzone")
[1] "UTC"
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Dirk. So if I have a data.frame in the "Date" format should I convert to POSIXlt, and then convert the data back to a data.frame/"Date" format?

Comment: I usually just extract the relavant information (say day-of-week) into a new column. Keep the date as type 'Date' and compute what you need next to it.

Comment: I see. I usually have problem with making my data POSIXlt and xts because when I use the `fix` command a lot and there is no way of viewing the data as you would in a data frame. Are you aware of any methods that would allow me to use these time series packages and at the same time see the data sets as a series of dated rows with variable columns running from left-to-right. Every time I try to see my data in xts format, I get this notepad file with the data in arranged in an intuitive format. Would appreciate your help on this Dirk and JB.

Comment: You never want to store as POSIXlt in a container such as a data.frame or xts object. Store as POSIXct, convert to POSIXlt on the fly and extract info you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lubridate` package to do a lot with dates.

From the help file: *Lubridate provides tools that make it easier to parse and manipulate dates.*

For example:

```
> library(lubridate)
> d <- today()
> d
[1] "2014-04-29"
> day(d)
[1] 29
> month(d)
[1] 4
> year(d)
[1] 2014
> week(d)
[1] 18
> weekdays(d)
[1] "Tuesday"
> days_in_month(d)
Apr 
 30
```

I prefer it to the built-in functions because it has a lot of date splicing, casting and arithmetic functions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options that I can think of.

First, you could use the class `as.POSIXlt` so that you can subset with things like `df$date$yday`. The `as.POSIXlt()` includes the elements of dates as a list underneath that can be accessed that way.

Also, the package `lubridate` has functions like

```
yday(x)
wday(x)
mday(x)
```